# Problem using NSRange: Index out of bounds

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsrange

I am trying to detect website URL's in my string and then doing some attribution string stuff like bolding it etc.

My regex is defined as:

```
static NSRegularExpression *websiteRegularExpression;
static inline NSRegularExpression * WebsiteRegularExpression() {
    if (!websiteRegularExpression) {
        websiteRegularExpression = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]" 
                                                                        options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                                          error:nil];
    }

    return websiteRegularExpression;
}
```

Here is where I enumerate:

```
 -(void)setBodyText
    {
        __block NSRegularExpression *regexp = nil;    
        bodyLabel.delegate = self;
        [self.bodyLabel setText:@"http://www.google.com" afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^NSAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {

            NSRange stringRange = NSMakeRange(0, [mutableAttributedString length]);

            regexp = WebsiteRegularExpression ();
            NSRange nameRange = [regexp rangeOfFirstMatchInString:[mutableAttributedString string] options:0 range:stringRange];
            UIFont *boldSystemFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0]; 
            CTFontRef boldFont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)boldSystemFont.fontName, boldSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
            if (boldFont) {
                [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(id)boldFont range:nameRange];
                CFRelease(boldFont);
            }

            [mutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:nameRange withString:[[[mutableAttributedString string] substringWithRange:nameRange] uppercaseString]];
            return mutableAttributedString;
        }];

        regexp = WebsiteRegularExpression();
        NSRange linkRange = [regexp rangeOfFirstMatchInString:self.bodyLabel.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [bodyLabel.text length])];
        [self.bodyLabel addLinkToURL:nil withRange:linkRange];
    }
```

I get the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'
```

How can I resolve?

Comment: can you post the regular expressions you are using? specifically what is mutableAttributedString. my guess is something is wrong in this line. [mutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:nameRange withString:[[[mutableAttributedString string] substringWithRange:nameRange] uppercaseString]]; you might want to debug it by making sure each step is giving you want you expected.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I've updated my code with the regex. Still not sure how to resolve...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the contents of *nameRange* before you call *substringWithRange*. If your regular expression doesn't match then the return value for [rangeOfFirstMatchInString](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/rangeOfFirstMatchInString%3aoptions%3arange%3a) will be

> {NSNotFound, 0}

[NSNotFound](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSNotFound) is defined as *NSIntegerMax* so you can imagine why this value might be out of range for your *mutableAttributedString*.

**Update for comment**

So to check the results of *substringWithRange*:

```
if (nameRange.location == NSNotFound)
    // didn't match the WebsiteRegularExpression() do something else
```

Comment: how can I check the contents of nameRange?

Comment: @sheehan-alam just check the location member on the range object (see update).

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere are you checking to see if any range you got back has the range.location = NSNotFound.  One of your matches is coming up empty and then you are trying to use the range for other things.

Comment: I am pretty new to NSRange, can you show me an example of how I could perform this check in my code?

Comment: Since RedBlue beat me to the response, I just up voted his answer.