# iPhone App crashes after localization of xib file

Tags: iphone, xcode4, localization

I am creating my first iPhone app in which the first screen displays a table view the user selects from. It works before localization using the method below.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

[self.window addSubview:[self.navigationController view]];

if(self.selectCategoryViewController == nil)
{
    SelectCategoryViewController *viewTwo = [[SelectCategoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectCategoryViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.selectCategoryViewController = viewTwo;
    [viewTwo release];
}
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];//this will hide the navigation bar
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.selectCategoryViewController animated:YES];


//self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

After I localized it by adding the Japanese localization file and changing the above to this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

[self.window addSubview:[self.navigationController view]];


if(self.selectCategoryViewController == nil)
{

    NSBundle *myLocalizedBundle=[NSBundle bundleWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath],"en.lproj"]];
    NSLog(@"the localized bundle is %@",myLocalizedBundle);
    SelectCategoryViewController *viewTwo=[[SelectCategoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectCategoryViewController" bundle:myLocalizedBundle];

    self.selectCategoryViewController = viewTwo;
    [viewTwo release];


}
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];//this will hide the navigation bar
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.selectCategoryViewController animated:YES];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

it crashes with the following error:

```
√sh.app> (loaded)
2013-02-18 18:04:35.196 PictureEnglish[5529:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString substringFromIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x012775a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x013cb313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0122fef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0122fe6a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   Foundation                          0x00033086 -[NSString substringFromIndex:] + 133
    5   PictureEnglish                      0x00008524 -[SelectCategoryViewController viewDidLoad] + 937
    6   UIKit                               0x00378089 -[UIViewController view] + 179
    7   UIKit                               0x00376482 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
    8   UIKit                               0x00386f25 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
    9   UIKit                               0x00385555 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    10  UIKit                               0x00386870 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 524
    11  UIKit                               0x0038132a -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    12  UIKit                               0x0049c2e9 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 226
    13  QuartzCore                          0x010a7a5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    14  QuartzCore                          0x010a9ddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0104f0b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    16  QuartzCore                          0x01050294 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    17  UIKit                               0x002ca9c9 -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 39
    18  UIKit                               0x002cae83 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 690
    19  UIKit                               0x002d5617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    20  UIKit                               0x002cdabf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    21  UIKit                               0x002d2f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x01bcf992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01258944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x011b8cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x011b5f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x011b5840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x011b5761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    28  UIKit                               0x002ca7d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    29  UIKit                               0x002d6c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    30  PictureEnglish                      0x00001cec main + 102
    31  PictureEnglish                      0x00001c7d start + 53
    32  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Any suggestions on how I should call the SelectCategoryViewController for the selected language?

Comment: you have... somewhere in your code.. substringWithRange / NSRange? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6515336/1702413

Comment: I am using it in the set up of the first view, but it does not crash before I localize the xib file (i.e. the nib). So I do not think that is the problem. It is as if it cannot find the localized file. Yet, when I have created a simple project with this same xib file but localized, it runs fine.  BTW, I am using Xcode 3.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks wrong to me:

```
NSBundle *myLocalizedBundle=[NSBundle bundleWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath],"en.lproj"]];
```

You probably meant something like this:

```
NSString* path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
NSBundle* bundle:myLocalizedBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
SelectCategoryViewController *viewTwo = [[SelectCategoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectCategoryViewController" bundle:myLocalizedBundle];
```

This is discussed more here: [Manually loading a different localized nib in iOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712049/manually-loading-a-different-localized-nib-in-ios)

Note that this is only required if you want to do an in-app language selection. Localization should typically use the iOS device's selected language, in which case all this is much more straightforward (you simply let iOS pick the bundle for you).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it is still crashing. Also, I agree with you that I should be able to localize the xib file and ios should  just use the corresponding nib file, but that is crashing too.

Comment: Hey, looking at your stack trace, your SelectCategoryViewController's viewDidLoad was executing when the exception occurred, so your nib definitely got loaded. The problem is in there, it's not due to the nib loading.

Comment: thanks. I was thinking that the file has a problem, but have absolutely no other ideas on what to do. Point of reference: when I right click on the xib file and select Get Info, then click the "Make File Localizable" button, I can then click the "Add Localization" button to add another new language. By doing this, it saves the English version of the xib in a English.lproj folder not en.lproj folder. I do not think the naming convention is causing the problem, but thought I would mention it here.

Answer (score 0):

xcode 5:
i had to clean build, clean build folder,delete derived data, reset simulator, close simulator, close Xcode.

Open project again and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Problem - This is a problem of project path, I think [self.window makeWindowKeyVisible] can not be able to find a path to your first assigned controller...
Solution - It happens some time, when your project suddenly stopped work, So no worries - just shift your project to other path, or just change the name of folder where actually your project resides and it will started working fine....

It works for me successfully...